# How to include the md5 value of a file into itself

Tags: md5

Supposed that you want to create a file which contains the md5 digest of itself. How to do that?
  Before you include the md5 value into the file, you have to calculate the value, but if and only if the md5 digest has been included into the file, you can calculate the value. It's kind o a dilemma. Any Idea?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that unless you use MD5 vulnerabilities you can't do that. I believe that even using MD5 vulnerabilities building such collision is impractical. A solution would be to either attach the digest at the end of the file or ship it separately.

Answer (score 0):

You have to avoid that cyclic dependency, so you can't checksum the checksum. To work around that, you could reserver space for the checksum in your file, but set that space to zeroes. Then calculate the checksum and embed it. In order to check it later, you'd have to read it in, and set those bytes in the file to zero again.